# Sign out has to be clicked twice in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

In my master page I have the signout. When I click the sign out button the below code is executed

```
protected void singout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
    }
```

and in the same master page my load is

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }
    private void LoadData()
    {
       Menu Items..
    }
```

When I click the signout the menu disappears as I do it in the page load based on role, so it means the role permission is stored in session so it gets cleared but the page has to redirect to Home.aspx but it remains in the same page, I have to click the sign out again for the page to redirect to home.aspx. WHere am I going wrong

Comment: This is where good debugging comes into play.  Step through your code and see what is happening on the second signout as opposed to the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the under mentioned code.

```
protected void singout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        Session.Abandon(); 
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null) 
        { 
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName); 
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d); 
            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie); 
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 
        }
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A logout operation can be facilitated solely by using [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) without touching the cookie in your code, and without the `if` statement. Forms Authentication will automatically take care of the cookie state for you.

This will also solve the problem of double sign-out because you are redirecting the user away from the protected page the first time the sign-out button is clicked.

```
protected void singout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    //Removes the forms-authentication ticket from the browser:
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 

    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    // ...or redirect the user to any place of choice outside the protected files. 

}
```